# How do I implement a terms query like under in Java? Anyway to use termsQuery() or other way?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

How do I implement a terms query like under in Java?
Anyway to use termsQuery() or other way?

```
{
       "terms": {
         "model_id": [
           "166168N",
           "753547",
           "1568357",
           "90112",
           "1020682",
           "3257438"
         ],
         "boost": 1.0E+6
       }
     }
```

Comment: are you using spring-data or JHLRC ?

Comment: I am using this dependency. elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client. I just need to frame this so that i can pass it in template as variable.

Comment: thanks but hope you know its deprecated in Elasticsearch 7.15, which Elasticsearch version you are using and if you want to upgrade Elasticsearch better to use new api-client

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: would suggest to upgrade the Elasticsearch server and client if you can, as new api client syntax is very different, and has a lot of new improvements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create query like below using Java high level client:

```java
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("userdoc");
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
String[] values = new String[] { "166168N", "753547", "1568357", "90112", "1020682", "3257438" };
searchSourceBuilder.query(new TermsQueryBuilder("model_id", values).boost(1));
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```